# How to validate a Credit Card Number with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a credit card number by a javascript function. I am taking an input by html form and want to validate at onblur event with it. I want to check input value is a number then card type and then luhn algorithm but I am unable to write the script still now.

Here is my code below :

```
function allnumeric()  
            {
            var inputtxt = document.form1.inputtxt; 
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;  
            if(inputtxt.value.match(numbers))  
                {  
                    if(visa(inputtxt))

                    {

                        if(function luhn(inputtxt))

                        {
                        return true;
                        }
                        else  
                        {   
                        return false;  
                        }

                    }

                    else if (function mastercard(inputtxt))

                    {

                        if(function luhn(inputtxt))

                        {
                        return true;
                        }
                        else  
                        {   
                        return false;  
                        }

                    }

                }   
            else  
            {  
            alert('Please enter your valid card number');  
            inputtxt.focus();  
            return false;  
            } 

function visa(inputtxt)  
{  
  var cardno = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(cardno))  
        {  
      return true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
        alert("Not a valid Visa credit card number!");  
        return false;  
        }  
}  

function mastercard(inputtxt)  
{  
  var cardno = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/;  
  if(inputtxt.value.match(cardno))  
        {  
      return true;  
        }  
      else  
        {  
        alert("Not a valid Mastercard number!");  
        return false;  
        }  

function luhn(inputtxt)
{
            /* Luhn check */
            var cc_sum = 0;
            var parsedCC;
            var cclen = inputtxt.length;
            for (i=cclen-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    var charati = inputtxt[i] + '';
                    parsedCC = parseInt(charati);
                    var oddeven = cclen-1 - i;
                    cc_sum += (oddeven%2 == 0) ? parsedCC :
                                    (parsedCC > 4) ? parsedCC * 2 % 10 + 1 :
                                            parsedCC * 2;
            }
            var checkvalid = ((cc_sum % 10) == 0) ? true : false;
            return checkvalid;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176802/how-to-validate-credit-card-number

Comment: Thank for your suggestion but I would like to check luhn algorithm too after getting card type :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend creating functions for each type of credit card. This will be a nightmare to maintain if changes are made to credit card formats, new cards introduced etc.

Unless your building a credit card validation plugin, the exact details of the credit card validation format should be abstract to you. Let someone else worry about that :)

The [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) has a [credit card validation method](http://jquery.bassistance.de/api-browser/plugins.html#jQueryvalidatormethodscreditcard) which I recommend you use.

Comment: Dear Curt, Thank you very much for your recommendation but I am in need to execute my code.