# Javascript not to let an input enter more or less

Tags: javascript

Javascript to accept 16 characters(all numbers), not less or not more

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
<div style="text-align:left;" class="form-group">
<label for="credit0_number">Credit Card Number</label>
<input type="number" class="inp form-control" id="credit0_number" name="credit0[number]" >
</div>
 </div>
```

I tried `maxlength = '16'` but it did not work I also did `min="16" max = "16"` , it didnt work as well what can I do?

Comment: Does it necessary have to be `number` instead of `text`?

Comment: Yes I only want to user numbers and not allow text @eeya

Comment: `type="number"` it is semantically not correct because credit card numbers are not measures. It's not meaningful as a number, its just a string that happens to consist of digits. This code will cause some browsers to show a text field with plus-minus buttons.

Comment: I used css to hide those @Midgard

Comment: @Sarah what wrong with `min` `max`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`maxlength` only limits the length of the input to 16 characters.  `Min` and `max` are only available for input type number and they limit the actual value, not the length of the value (length of the string).

I believe you are trying to validate a credit card? You could use the pattern attribute and a regular expression:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" required>
```

This means any number containing the digits 0-9 and 13-16 chars in length.  If you only want to allow 16 chars, try this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{16}" required>
```

Comment: It enters letters, I only want numbers that why I have type = "number"

Comment: No it just let me enter letters

Comment: Yeah but you cannot submit the value.

Comment: Can it show an error on the spot? without having to submit the form yet?

Comment: @Sarah You can read more about the `pattern` attribute and the way they validate content [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

You may also want to read more about event driven form validation through JavaScript and even server-side validation.

Comment: @sarah, no not really.  This is using the built in validation provided by HTML5 and it's much more limited than a custom made JS solution.  For a more robust solution, check out some Javascript implementations (and don't forget to perform the validation also on the backend!). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176802/how-to-validate-credit-card-number

Answer (score 0):

If these input fields are wrapped in a form, you can use an [onsubmit] listener on the form.

If you are using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can do that like this:

```
$("#id-of-your-form").on("submit", function(event) {
    var len = $("#credit0_number").val().length;
    if (len != 16) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Show an error message here
    }
});
```

### EDIT

If you also want to check on keyup, you could do something like this:

```
function validCredit() {
    return $("#credit0_number").val().length == 16;
}

$("#id-of-your-form").on("submit", function(event) {
    if (!validCredit()) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Show an error message here
    }
});

$("#credit0_number").on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (!validCredit()) {
        // Show an error message here
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I do on keyup?

Comment: You can, but you should then also check on submit. I've edited that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @HaukurHaf's answer, you need wrap your form with `<form>` to show the validation message.

### Without  tag:

```html
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div style="text-align:left;" class="form-group">
    <label for="credit0_number">Credit Card Number</label>
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" required>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

### With  tag:

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div style="text-align:left;" class="form-group">
      <label for="credit0_number">Credit Card Number</label>
      <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" required>
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can i have the message show on a keyup instead of a form?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use HTML5 attributes, you may want to have a pure JavaScript implementation using **regular expressions** and the `input` event (`click` and `keyup` are not good enough because the user can use his mouse or keyboard with an `input[type="number"]` ).

The pattern you want is certainly `/^\d{16}$/` to be sure that there are only 16 numbers in the field.

```js
var num = document.getElementById('num');

num.addEventListener('input', handler, false);

function handler() {
  var pattern = /^\d{16}$/;
  if (pattern.test(num.value)) {
    console.log('---> OK <---');
  } else {
    console.log('KO');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number">
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try to put the input inside a form?

And using a pattern works fine for me:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{16}">
```

Answer (score -1):

Add an onkeypress to allow only numbers to keyed. Then add an input pattern to only allow 16 characters.

```html
<form>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div style="text-align:left;" class="form-group">
      <label for="credit0_number">Credit Card Number</label>
      <input pattern="[0-9]{16}" type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
      <input type="submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That is fairly hackish. Users are now blocked from doing Ctrl+V to paste, and can still rightclick and paste non-numerical values.

Comment: The pattern ".{16}" means "16 of anything". Later on you are testing if the pressed character is a number, so why wouldn't you simply say "16 digits", namely using the pattern "[0-9]{16}"

Comment: I can still Ctrl+V to paste and pasting non-numerical values are present for all the other solutions here too. So I'm not sure why there's a downvote. I did make an error however which I will edit. Missing numerical validation: `<input pattern="[0-9]{16}"`.

Comment: @Jason given that edit, the onkeypress isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: @thepieterdc Well theres a older post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input The onkeypress might not be necessary but I don't see a big problem with it as an addition. Nothing beats server-side validation in the end. But is there a real problem with the onkeypress?

Comment: @Jason ofcourse you always need serverside validation, you can never trust your user, but what I mean is that when you are using a pattern, the onkeypress wouldn't do anything I guess since the pattern would cover this

Comment: @thepieterdc as commented before in the answer post, the non-numeric value will not be submitted. But it can still be keyed. I guess in the wider schemes of things, its not necessary but it kind of simulates serverside validation. You see it often in creditcard/dates/sort-codes inputs.