# Algorithm for detecting completion of credit card number input

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for an algorithm to do what Stripe Elements does when it moves the cursor to the expiry month once the credit card number max length has been reached considering that every card type seems to have their own lengths and algorithms.

To clarify my question: I am not looking for another credit card validator.

A credit card number of `4242 4242 4242 42` is valid but were I to move the cursor to the next field I would be doing the user a disservice because their full card number is `4242 4242 4242 4242`. I want to detect when the full number, ie maximum length has been reached per credit card type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate a credit card number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176802/how-to-validate-a-credit-card-number)

Comment: No, because the number could be valid but not yet complete. Stripe have some detecting of the maximum length

Comment: But... an incomplete card number is not a valid card number, it only becomes valid (and would match a valid card check) once it is complete.

Comment: see my updated question for an explanation

Comment: Can both '4242 4242 4242 42' and '4242 4242 4242 4242' of same card type can be valid? The example @DBS provided checks the card depending of its type. So if same type of card cant have different length it should work.

Comment: @mursalin Some prefixes have multiple lengths, so maybe it's possible, but perhaps wouldn't pass the Luhn check.

Comment: can you create object which will store card-max-length or regex for different card types and then verify using that.